# Inference of Locust result

Tags: python, testing, performance-testing, load-testing, locust

Locust Report

```
NUM REQUESTS 500
NUM CLIENTS 50
NUM HATCH RATE 10
 Name                                 # reqs      # fails     Avg     Min     Max  |  Median   req/s
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 POST /someurl                           549     0(0.00%)      43      27     103  |      44   40.90
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Total                                   549     0(0.00%)                                      40.90

Percentage of the requests completed within given times
 Name                                 # reqs    50%    66%    75%    80%    90%    95%    98%    99%   100%
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 POST /someurl                           549     44     48     50     51     55     57     63     68    103
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Here, the number of failure cases are 0.

The number of requests is **500** but, total requests in report is **549**

Can anyone please explain why there is inconsistency.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you running it with `--no-reset-stats`? If so, that will... not reset stats once the clients hatch completely (which is when the 500 requests start).

Comment: yeah I'm running with `--no-reset-stats`. But still, I'm afraid that I couldnt understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you start clients, Locust does two things:

1. It creates locusts, based on your hatch rate and number of Locusts specified
2. These all start making requests
3. Once all Locusts spawn, the number of requests is reset

   - Unless using `--no-reset-stats`

Because you are using `--no-reset-stats` this means that any of the requests made in the hatching period will count towards your total, even though the count for 500 does not start until all are hatched.